# How to reapply directive when scope is changed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Say you have something like this:

```
<div mydirective>
  {{boundtoscope}}
</div>
```

And you want mydirective to be applied on change of $scope.boundtoscope.  How do you direct Angular to reapply the directive?

Comment: [This is how ng-bind directive does it.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L55)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your directive's link function $watch the scope property:

```
myApp.directive('mydirective', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('boundtoscope', function(newValue) {
          alert('boundtoscope changed');
          // do something here
      });
    }
  }
});
```

If `boundtoscope` is an array or an object map, and you want to look for changes to items within the array/object, set the [objectEquality argument](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) to `true` to perform a "shallow" watch (i.e., compare the array/object for equality rather than for reference):

```
  scope.$watch('boundtoscope', function(newValue) {
      alert('boundtoscope changed')
  }, true);    // "shallow" compare
```

Angular 1.2 adds a new method for this, [$watchCollection](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection):

```
  scope.$watchCollection('boundtoscope', function(newValue) {
      alert('boundtoscope changed')
  });  // also does a "shallow" compare
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Exactly what I needed, and wasn't obvious from the documentation.

Comment: I was totally going to do a whole bunch of convoluted stuff like actually copying and removing the element and then throwing it back in there. This is _much_ simpler. Thank you!

Comment: As I understand it, it is better to do things like watching the `$scope` in the directive's controller rather than in the linker; the linker is more intended for one-time DOM manipulation. This is my interpretation of things after reading [this book](http://www.manning.com/bford/) and some general reading around the internet on the topic. I'm happy to be corrected though!